# AngularJS ng-repeat from array not iterating. (Cordova Android)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, rss

I have a Cordova Android app, running Ionic, and I have a script that gets RSS Feeds from multiple URLs.

To make sure that it doesn't just store the last feeds entries in the local storage, I have made an array where I push each RSS Feeds' entries into it so that I can display all the entires from all the feeds.

This is how I've set up the array:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.entryDB = [];
});
```

This is how the code for fetching each RSS Feed looks:

```
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql("SELECT (data) FROM note", [], function(tx,res){
              for(var iii = 0; iii < res.rows.length; iii++){


                  alert(res.rows.item(iii).data);

                  $http.get("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + res.rows.item(iii).data)
                     .success(function(data) {
                         $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
                         $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
                         $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
                         $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;

                         window.localStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries));
                         $scope.entryDB.push(JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries));
                         alert($scope.entryDB)
                     })
                     .error(function(data) {
                         console.log("ERROR: " + data);
                         if(window.localStorage["entries"] !== undefined) {
                             $scope.entries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage["entries"]);
                         }
                     });
              }
          });
      }, function(err){
          alert("An error occured while displaying saved notes");
      });
```

*(res.rows.item(iii).data is each feed's URL)*

The weird thing is that when I try to display the entries using ng-repeat, if I use the entryDB array, it only outputs the entire array as one entry in HTML, but if I use the localStorage "Entries", it works perfectly fine by iterating properly and displaying multiple card items.

I have tried doing alert() to both the localStorage entry and the entryDB entry and they look identical, but ng-repeat won't iterate over the entryDB entries.

This is how I'm trying to display the entires:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="FeedController" ng-init="init()" class="has-tabs-top">

    <!-- // List of Cards // -->
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="entry in entryDB">

      <!-- // Card Title // -->
      <div class="item item-divider">{{entry.link}}</div>
      <!-- // Card Contents // -->
      <div class="item item-body" ng-click="browse(entry.link)">
        <h2><b>{{entry.title}}</b></h2>
        <p>{{entry.contentSnippet}}</p>
        <p><a class="subdued">{{entry.publishedDate}}</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

If I try to just display {{entry}}, I can see that it's successfully getting the entire entryDB array, but it won't iterate and just displays one card item with the entire array on it.

Been stuck at this now for 2 days and I've tried looking online for hours - Iæve tried adding 'track by $index' to the ng-repeat but that didn't work either.

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to angularJS so would appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line    `$scope.entryDB.push(JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries));`

to

```
$scope.entryDB.push(data.responseData.feed.entries);
```

Comment: Hmm, now the alert for entryDB shows that it contains [object Object],[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]. There are indeed 4 entries in the feed, perhaps now I just need to edit it from the HTML?

Comment: Do you know how I could display them? I have tried only showing 'entry' but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried showing it using "<h2><b>{{entry}}</b></h2>", but it's still just giving me the entire array as one entry.

Comment: Yes! When I tried adding [0] to the end of each 'entry', I can now see the single entry inside the array. How could I index through all the entires though to make it show each one in the array?

Comment: Change html as per requirement

Comment: Could you clarify? Is it possible to create a for-loop inside the HTML code that would iterate for the length of the array?

Comment: ng-repeat is for loop in html

Comment: I tried adding 'track by $index' to my ng-repeat, but how can I then get that index inside the entry[]?

Comment: can you paste your server response some where

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I am building a cordova app for android and it's running on the device, so I don't have a console unfortunately.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it does not work for me now because some of the js only loads on device it seems.

Comment: I tried using entry[$index] and also [$index + 1] but it does not iterate through.

Comment: i cannot help you properly without seeing response

Comment: I understand. I will try to get it running on my computer so I can check logs.